# Confused about a question on RLC circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

[image]

Question: Find the current 'I' after a long time.

I got that the answer is 2.66mA, but it is not the correct answer and I don't know why.
There is no current on the capacitor after a long time because after a long time it is "full", so I ignore it.
Also, after a long time I assume that the induction coil is just a normal wire after a long time.
So after that I just added together the resistors according to the Series and Parallel rules and got that the answer is 2.66 mA.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Yes so after all my assumptions I got that only the resistors are left on the circuit, while the induction coil "turned" into normal wire and the capacitor "turned" into an open switch. So I added the 2 resistors on the right together which is 9.4, than I added them all in parallel: 1/(1/4.7 + 1/4.7 + 1/9.4)=1.88  => I=V/R => 5/1.88 => 2.66 This is a multi choice question and my options are: 0 , 0.27mA , 2.66mA , 1.06mA. I chose 2.66mA and it is wrong...

Comment: Does the presence of a capacitor or inductor effect the current flowing through the circuit? IF so, then you need to be more careful, e.g. have the equation for current as a function of time (which should be exponential) and take the limit for large times

Comment: Did you draw the arror or did they?

Comment: @R.Emery they did, it is the current they want me to find out.

Comment: @N.Steinle the questions states that t= infinite

Comment: It looks like that image comes from a book.  Does the answer come from the book, or your instructor?

Comment: @garyp its sort of multiple answer online homework assignment with limited tries.

Comment: I'm starting to think maybe the teacher was wrong and put the wrong answer as the answer. I sent her a mail to check the question, waiting for an answer.

Comment: Was the question originally written in English, or did you translate it? Can you share the exact wording?

Comment: @ThePhoton I translated it... The question should be quite simple, I think the teacher made a mistake because everyone here agrees with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The teacher was incorrect, and my calculations are right. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score -4):

A simple answer would be to know that after a long time, the circuit comes in a steady state. Now in steady-state, an inductor behaves like a short-circuit, and a capacitor like an open circuit. So when u substitute the inductors with a wire and remove the capacitor, the equivalent resistance of the circuit becomes 7.83 kilo-ohms. Now, when u find the current comes out to be 0.638 mA. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Check your math

Comment: Calculate the current through the first resistor. Total current will be 2.5 times that

Comment: I don't think so (: Can you be a bit more clear)

Comment: Is there not an equal amount of current through the second resister and half as much through the last 2 resisters?

Comment: It is impossible that a resistor of $4.7 k\Omega$ in parallel to other ones results in a greater impedance of $7.83 k\Omega$.